# TortoiseSVN Login not working after Windows AD Password Change

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We are using VisualSVN as Subversion Server with Windows AD as authentification.

Yesterday I changed my Windows AD password.
I connected to the VisualSVN-Webserver which worked fine with the new password.

But I couldn't log in to the server using TortoiseSVN.
I cleared the cache of Tortoise and even reinstalled it, but the problem stays the same.

So I know for sure, that the new password is correct and VisualSVn-authetification works fine with Windows AD, but still Tortoise isn't working.

Comment: What authentication type is selected in VisualSVN Server settings? Is it Integrated Windows Authentication? Do you have your old credentials saved in Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: I solved it. In Germany we use ö, ä, ü. Our SVN Version couldn't handle this as it is very old...

Comment: Upgrade your server. This problem has been already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Germany we use ö, ä, ü. Our SVN Version couldn't handle this as it
>   is very old.

The problem has been solved in [VisualSVN Server 3.5.0](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.5.0):

> - Fixed: unable to authenticate using Windows Basic Authentication when a password contains non-ASCII characters.